# ¿Por qué no me guarda mi hoja en formato .csv?

Tags: excel, vba

Cree la siguiente macro en Excel para guardar una hoja como valores separados por comas (CSV) como un nuevo archivo `.txt`:

```vb
Sub GuardarHojacomoCVS()
    LibroActual = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Teresa\Desktop\respaldo tere" & "\libro1.txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & LibroActual
End Sub
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo, ¿por qué no guarda el archivo?

Comment: La línea para guardar el archivo está bien. ¿Te da algún error? ¿Te fijaste en la carpeta y no creó el archivo `libro1.txt`?

Comment: Hola Teresa, ¿Podrías aclarar tu problema? No me queda claro si es que no te lo guarda en formato .csv o bien directamente no te lo guarda (por tu pregunta final). ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que el `SaveAs` pregunta al usuario con una notificación dónde quiere guardarlo, cómo nombrarlo, etc...

Para solucionarlo puedes deshabilitar temporalmente los avisos (como explican en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22305396/1468942)) utilizando `Application.DisplayAlerts` por lo que tu código quedaría así:

```
Sub GuardarHojacomoCVS()    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    LibroActual = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Teresa\Desktop\respaldo tere" & "\libro1.txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & LibroActual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

De esta manera primero desactivamos los avisos y luego los volvemos a activar.

Si lo que queremos es guardar una *copia* en lugar de utilizar `SaveAs` utilizamos [`SaveCopyAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx)

Comment: Me parece que esa respuesta de SO es para `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`. En el caso de esta pregunta, creo que sólo si el archivo ya existe le mostraría el diálogo *`desea sobreescribir..?`*. Pero no creo que por eso esté preguntando "*Por qué no me guarda*"... De todas formas, es cuestión de que la autora explique un poco mejor el caso.

Comment: @Mariano por lo que he leído un poco buscando en Google (COUGH) parece ser que sí salta un dialog igualmente.. O al menos eso me ha parecido, voy a mirarlo otra vez (mirado: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/67564-visual-basic-applications-code-save-workbook-no-prompt.html). Y tengo dudas de si le guarda o no el archivo por su pregunta final (aunque el título de la pregunta sea otro).

Comment: Lo probé recién y cuando no existe el archivo lo graba sin problemas. Si existe, muestra el diálogo y permite sobreescribir. Quizás sólo esté preguntando por qué no tiene la extensión `.csv` :-)  .. Publico eso como respuesta y cuando vuelva vemos

Comment: ¿Puede ser entonces por el  `.txt`?

Comment: Supongo recién ahora... Cuando se despierte @TeresaCastro nos enteraremos

Comment: Hola a todos gracias por sus comentarios, ya cambie la extensión a csv y lo que hace, es efectivamente guardar la hoja en ese formato, pero mi archivo actual ( en donde tengo el boton) tambien me lo guarda con extension csv y ese archivo, el original no debe convertirse.

Comment: En lugar de `SaveAs` utiliza `SaveCopyAs` =P